# Screen tearing with Nvidia Prime

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, bumblebee, nvidia-prime

I've installed Nvidia-346 (that also installed Prime) and prime-indicator from the `ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8` repository in Ubuntu 15.04.

Whenever I switch from Intel to nVidia I get a general screen tearing in my laptop and it can't be solved with all the solutions that I've found to solve common nVidia tearing issues.

Is this normal? Do I have to live with it?

Also, I tried with Bumblebee but I can't install the Bumblebee repository correctly and the bumblebee with nVidia installation on Ubuntu repos for some reason uses nouveau whenever I run `optirun glxgears -info | grep "GL_VENDOR"` to try it.

Comment: That you see `nouveau` is normal as it's a repackaged version of the proprietary drivers.  For the other problems, see the link below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)